# Dynamics Onmichannel integration with Azure Bot Framework

Tags: twilio, botframework, dynamics-crm, whatsapp

We have integrated Azure Bot Dynamics omnichannel with Twilio. Omnichannel is expected to route the messages to Azure Bot that we have built. The routing rules have been created. We are now able to get the messages from Whatsapp-Twilio-Omnichannel-Bot. Bot has inbuilt logic replies to incoming messages. The outgoing message replies are not going back the the channel. The transcript is also not traceble. Can anybody guide how to solve the problem.

Best Regards

Comment: Are you following [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/configure-whatsapp-channel)? Are you integrating with the Twilio WhatsApp sandbox for testing? Have you sent the join phrase from your own phone so that you can interact with it? Does the bot have any logging for issues? Have you seen any [errors in Twilio logs](https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/debugger/events?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fdebugger%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1&currentFrameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fdebugger%3F__override_layout__%3Dembed%26quickDate%3D720%26x-target-region%3Dus1%26bifrost%3Dtrue)?

Comment: Yes we are following the guide as you have mentioned. We are using Twilio WhatsApp Sandbox, We have already configured our own phones by sending join phrase to WA number. There no issue on BOT end. There are not Twilio error logs. We have observed that there is no locale info attached to message when message is arriving in bot.

Comment: So, when you send a message to the WhatsApp number it arrives at the bot? And when you send a message to the WhatsApp number the bot should respond with an automatic reply? Is that based on code or a bot you have written and deployed, or is that something configured in Dynamics?  (I'm sorry, I haven't used Twilio's WhatsApp API through Dynamics Omnichannel, I work at Twilio and can maybe help if there's an error on our side, but I need more explanation to help more on the Dynamics side.)

Comment: Yes you are right. The message arrives in Bot but when bot responds message is not flowing to Whatsapp